# Retrieve angular expression in a ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to retrieve an angular expression from the ng-init content, but it doesn't seems to work and the ng-model is null. Here's my code.

```
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.role"
    ng-init="user.role={{user.lastname}}-{{state | limitTo:2}}-{{ city| limitTo:2}}"
                           disabled>
```

Note : state and city are selected from a dropdownlist and i just want to take the first 2 chars.

When i remove the {{}} it's not working as expected because i got only the first 2 chars for all the expression.
What i should have : **Turner-US-NY** but what i get : **Tu**

Any working solution ? Thanks

Comment: `limitTo filter will work on array..not on string..you need to create custom filter which will act as truncate

Comment: @PankajParkar you can techincally apply limitTo on string as string is a char array. Issue here is with interpolation, this should just be `user.role=user.lastname + '-' + (state | limitTo:2) '-' + ( city| limitTo:2)` though this will work, using ng-init for this is wrong i guess.

Comment: Are you trying to limit USA to US and NYC to NY or are you expecting United States of America will be shortened to US when used with limitTo?

Comment: @PSL yes your guess is right..he might wanted to bind value of dropdown on its change..

Comment: @PankajParkar What i meant is limitTo will truncate string as well.

Comment: @PSL yes...you are right I tried that it worked http://plnkr.co/edit/yiLShrwER0DdQxE3zHHE?p=preview

Comment: Hi PSL, yes i'm trying to limit USA to US and NYC to NY because the user select USA and NYC in the dropdownlist. When i display the data in a div : {{user.lastname}}-{{state | limitTo:2}}-{{ city| limitTo:2}} it works and the div is updated when there's live changes. But i just want to pass this string to my ng-model.

Comment: @user708683 Did you read the comments above? Also you should set the model on ng-change of the dropdown then. ng-init will not register a watch and reevaluate the expression.

Comment: @PSL Yes i've read your comment. And i also applied the ng-change for my dropdownlist and this is how i retrieve the state and city value. but i cannot apply the limitTo in the ng-change cause it will solve my issue from the begining

Comment: ng-model="user.info=user.lastname + '-' + (state | limitTo:2) '-' + ( city| limitTo:2)" solve it and i'm able to pass all the string in my model user.info and save it to my DB. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Consolidating all the comments into an answer:

1. Use `ng-change` to recalculate `user.role`. `ng-init` will not do what you need.
2. Consider using a function in the controller instead of expressions

So, the final result is something like this:

```
<select ng-model="state" ng-options="..."
        ng-change="recalcUserRole()">

<select ng-model="city" ng-options="..."
        ng-change="recalcUserRole()">

<input ng-model="user.role">
```

```
$scope.recalcUserRole = function(){
  $scope.user.role = $scope.user.lastname + '-' 
                   + $scope.state.substring(0,2) + '-'
                   + $scope.city.substring(0,2);
}
```

If you insist on using expressions in the View, then it could be done like so:

```
<select ng-model="state" ng-options="..."
    ng-change="user.role = user.lastname+'-'+state.substring(0,2)+'-'+city.substring(0,2)">
```

Comment: Best solution so far !. Thank you everyone. I'm new with angular and with your help i learned a lot :)